# Python SSH Connection with Paramiko & Netmiko libs

Tags: python, networking, paramiko

If anyone could give a help, i have an issue with hop ssh conections.
I can´t use (Netmiko SSH Proxy Support by Keith), maybe because i´m running in windows box.

So I connect via `ssh` to hop server and then to router using `paramiko` lib. Next I want to pull netmiko to send/retrive commands/outputs, but I allways receive errors with the ConnectHandler when I start the ssh connection with paramiko:

```
ERROR:
line 40, in <module>
    net_connect = ConnectHandler(device_type='cisco_ios', ip='x', username='x', password='x')
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\netmiko\ssh_dispatcher.py", line 96, in ConnectHandler
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\netmiko\base_connection.py", line 89, in __init__
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\netmiko\base_connection.py", line 396, in establish_connection
netmiko.ssh_exception.NetMikoTimeoutException: Connection to device timed-out: cisco_ios x.x.x.x:22
```

Below my (simple) code, i am really fresh in programming, so my code can be awful :(.

```
import paramiko
import netmiko
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
from getpass import getpass
import time
import re
import sys

# First ssh connection
remote_conn_pre=paramiko.SSHClient()
remote_conn_pre.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
remote_conn_pre.connect(ip, port=22, username=username,  
                        password=password,
                        look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False)

remote_conn = remote_conn_pre.invoke_shell()
output = remote_conn.recv(65535)
print output

# Second SSH connection
remote_conn.send("ssh x@ip x \n>")
time.sleep(3)
remote_conn.send("password\n")
output1 = remote_conn.recv(65535)
print output1
time.sleep(3)

# Trying to run netmiko...
net_connect = ConnectHandler(device_type='cisco_ios', ip='x.x.x.x', username='user', password='password') 
net_connect.find_prompt()

CISCO_SHOW_ACL_x = net_connect.send_command("show run | s access-list x ")
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of `device_type='cisco_ios'` => use `'device_type': 'cisco_ios'`, it might be a syntax thing